# How to open a .img/.rrd satellite image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a couple of multispectral satellite images which are in .img/.rrd format and I want to oopen them in Matlab for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure Matlab can recognise .img /.rdd files directly, but you could try using ImageJ or Fiji to convert your .img files to one of the image formats that is accepted. e.g. tiff, png, bmp, jpeg. The list of accepted formats can be found by typing 'imformats' in the command line.